# Get only the PDF files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little problem with my code in VBA, How can I exclude the other extension file like `.txt, .csv, .xlsx, and .xlsm` so I can select only in my `For Each Loop` is the `.PDF` extension only.

I've already searched about this issue and already tried, But the solution is not applicable in my code.

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetPDFFile()
Dim mainWs As Worksheet
Dim pdfPath As Variant, excelPath As Variant
Dim fileSystemObject As New fileSystemObject
Dim getFolderPath As Folder
Dim getFile As file
Dim wb As Workbook

Set mainWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

pdfPath = mainWs.Range("C7").Value
excelPath = mainWs.Range("C8").Value

'Set all variable to null
Call SetNothing

If pdfPath = "" Then
    Call MsgActionInvalid("Please input PDF File Folder.")
ElseIf excelPath = "" Then
    Call MsgActionInvalid("Please input Output Folder Location.")
Else
    Set getFolderPath = fileSystemObject.getFolder(pdfPath)

    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")

    If cntFiles <> 0 Then

    For Each getFile In getFolderPath.Files

         `Other code............
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm getting all the files inside the folder that I've selected. So inside the `For Each Loop` I'm getting a debug message because the file is not `.PDF`.

Any ideas about this guys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-property-filesystemobject-object) of the [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object) like `getFile.Type` to find out its type. And use a `If` statement to run your ``Other code............` only on the desired type of files.

Comment: Thank for the idea, I got it now. I've added code inside the `For Each`.  This `If` Statement. `If getFile Like "*.PDF*" Then 'Other Code End If`.

Comment: I would remove the `*` in the end. Otherwise this would be true for `Not_A_.PDF_File.xls` too. Only use `Like "*.PDF"`

Comment: I'd use `If Right(getFile,4)=".PDF"` to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Oooh!, I didn't noticed that. Thank you again.

Comment: Don't forget to make it case insensitive. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Type property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-property-filesystemobject-object) of the [File object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object) like `getFile.Type` to find out its type. And use a If statement to run your `Other code............` only on the desired type of files.

---

Alternatively use `UCase(getFile) Like "*.PDF"` to make sure that it is not case sensitive. Otherwise you only trigger `.PDF` but not `.Pdf` or `.pdf` or `.pDf` or whatever.

Which is the same as `UCase(Right$(getFile, 4)) = ".PDF"`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Right` to check the file extension. Something like:

```
For Each getFile In getFolderPath.Files
    If Right(getFile, 4) = ".pdf" Then
        ' have found a PDF extension............
    End If
Next
```

Regards,